# Allow only 1 selected option on multiple select fields

Tags: javascript

I have multiple select fields with all the same options. If one option has been selected in 1 select field, the same option should be removed from all the other fields. Well, that should not be a problem, since my code already does that job. The problem is when I re-select an option. For instance, on select field 1, I select the option "Fiel 1". That option has now been removed from all the other select fields. Now when I select another option on the same field, the option "Field 1" has been removed from all the other fields, even if it's no longer selected.

However, my goal is that a selected option should be selected only once. So if it's selected, it should be removed from all the other fields and if it's not selected anywhere, it should be a valid option everywhere.

This is what I have tried so far:

```js
const levels = document.querySelectorAll('select');
let fields = ['Field 1', 'Field 2', 'Field 3', 'Field 4', 'Field 5'];
let missingOptions = [];

for (let level of levels) {
  level.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    //console.log(e.target.value);
    for (let level of levels) {
      if (level !== e.target) {
        for (let i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
          if (level.options[i].value == e.target.value) {
            level.remove(i);
            if (!missingOptions.includes(e.target.value)) {
              missingOptions.push(e.target.value);
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {

      if (level.options[i].value != e.target.value) {

        for (let missingOption of missingOptions) {
          for (let l of levels) {
            // console.log(level.options[i].value, 'the value');
            // console.log(missingOptions.includes(level.options[i].value), 'is in array');
            if (missingOptions.includes(level.options[i].value)) {
              var index = missingOptions.indexOf(level.options[i].value);

              if (index > -1) { //if found
                missingOptions.splice(index, 1);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

  });
}
```

```html
<h1>Sorting</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <strong>Level 1</strong><br>
<select name="" id="1">
  <option value="Field 1">Field 1</option>
  <option value="Field 2">Field 2</option>
  <option value="Field 3">Field 3</option>
  <option value="Field 4">Field 4</option>
  <option value="Field 5">Field 5</option>
</select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Level 2</strong><br>
<select name="" id="2">
  <option value="Field 1">Field 1</option>
  <option value="Field 2">Field 2</option>
  <option value="Field 3">Field 3</option>
  <option value="Field 4">Field 4</option>
  <option value="Field 5">Field 5</option>
</select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Level 3</strong><br>
<select name="" id="3">
  <option value="Field 1">Field 1</option>
  <option value="Field 2">Field 2</option>
  <option value="Field 3">Field 3</option>
  <option value="Field 4">Field 4</option>
  <option value="Field 5">Field 5</option>
</select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The bad thing about my code is that it uses too many loops. I am sure that there will be a much better solution.

Comment: Why do you remove the options from the DOM? Just toggle their [`.disabled`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#htmloptionelement) property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of selected options and disable the option in other `select` element.

```js
const selectedOptions = Array(3).fill('');
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', e => {
  const selects = document.querySelectorAll('select');
  selectedOptions[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
  [...selects].forEach(select => {
    if(e.target.id !== select.id) {
      const options = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
      [...options].forEach((option) => {
        option.disabled = selectedOptions.includes(option.value);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<h1>Sorting</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <strong>Level 1</strong><br>
      <select name="" id="1">
        <option value="Field 1">Field 1</option>
        <option value="Field 2">Field 2</option>
        <option value="Field 3">Field 3</option>
        <option value="Field 4">Field 4</option>
        <option value="Field 5">Field 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Level 2</strong><br>
      <select name="" id="2">
        <option value="Field 1">Field 1</option>
        <option value="Field 2">Field 2</option>
        <option value="Field 3">Field 3</option>
        <option value="Field 4">Field 4</option>
        <option value="Field 5">Field 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Level 3</strong><br>
      <select name="" id="3">
        <option value="Field 1">Field 1</option>
        <option value="Field 2">Field 2</option>
        <option value="Field 3">Field 3</option>
        <option value="Field 4">Field 4</option>
        <option value="Field 5">Field 5</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```